# Cannot access columns with german umlauts in Laravel 5 using sqlsrv

Tags: php, laravel, sqlsrv

I use an existing db on our SQL-Server 2008 with Laravel 5.

Many tables and columns contain german umlauts. I've set the charset of the connection to "utf8" and can access tables like `Läger` without problems. 
But I couldn't access columns with umlauts. Every query returns something like

```
["Stra�e"]=> string(15) "Mainzer Str. 97"
```

instead of

```
["Straße"]
```

I've tested it with charset utf8 and latin1 but it's always the same result.

Any idea how to fix this without changing the existing db?

Comment: Have you tired ISO/IEC 8859-15 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15

Comment: @DenisPriebe Yes. I've tried every possible Charset on the connection but it's always the same result. The returned values in the collection are displayed correctly but the fields look like this. I've also tested different versions of the sqlsrv driver and different versions of php. If I build a mysql db with the same columns/tables it works fine but i have to use the existing db.

Comment: Perhaps it's the page, not sqlsrv... Have you tried setting the charset in the page headers too? i.e. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`. For the sqlsrv connection options, the only possible values of `CharacterSet` are `SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR` and `"UTF-8"` [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @ImClarky The page ist configured correct. If i use an mysql sb it works fine. It seems to be an issue with the driver. https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/138