# PHP PDO_SQLSRV: encoding error with column containing accented chars

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm getting back "�" instead of accented chars in my PSO_SQLSRV querys. This is how i connect to the db:

```
$dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=' . $this->host . ';Database=' . $this->dbname;
`$options` = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

try {
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    new DatabaseErrorHandler($e);
}
```

I tried adding `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8` to my `$options` array, but nothing changes. Db collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

I'm using Microsoft driver `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` with PHP 5.6.14

Comment: The data has to have been stored using an encoding that understands these extended character sets and also displayed on a page that understands UTF-8. Show the `<head>` of the page displaying this data

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in my `<head>`. I'm having this problem from the column names at the moment, still have to try with table content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490953/cannot-access-columns-with-german-umlauts-in-laravel-5-using-sqlsrv . In that post the OP says there maybe be something wrong with the drivers and there is an [issue posted on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/138)

Comment: @ImClarky thanks, this is so frustrating :(